# How to get "ID" value from "name[ID][OTHER]" in attribute of element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, attributes

I have a form which use for adding some information names like `name[ID][other]`

```
<select id="ADD_ICON" name="ADD_LINK[123][ICON]" class="bs-select form-control change_add_link" data-show-subtext="true" data-width="65px">...
```

now I want to work with this in jQuery. For that I have to access to the ID of this element.
How I can get the `ID` - in the example above - how I can get `123`?

Comment: Please share your current code.

Comment: please review [ask] and include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are asking for this line of code. I would recommend trying to google your question first.

```
var name=$(select).attr('name');
var matches = name.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
var number=matches[1];
```

Comment: no, if i do that i get "ADD_LINK[123][ICON]" but my question is how i can get only the "123" part of the ID

Comment: you mean the 'name' attribute not id

Comment: yes sorry not the id = attribute, i mean the ID "123" in the middle of the name - how can i get them?

Answer (score 0):

You should get `name` attribute of element then trying to select specific part of that string. You can use regex in [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to do this work.

```js
var val = $("#ADD_ICON").attr("name").match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1];
console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ADD_ICON" name="ADD_LINK[123][ICON]" class="bs-select form-control change_add_link" data-show-subtext="true" data-width="65px">...
```

Also you can use only javascript

```
var val = document.getElementById("ADD_ICON").name.match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1];
```